# Mudar a url de acesso conforme ip no htacess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Possuo um sistema que está todo configurando com o endereço de forma fixa no código, por exemplo: 'site.producao.com.br', e está no ip 10.109.104.27, porém o servidor de desenvolvimento está no http://site.dev no ip 10.108.105.59.

Existe uma forma de no htacess fazer com que caso o ip seja o de dev ( .59 ) ele aponte para a url 'site.dev'? Sem precirar alterar o código todo?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Tente.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10.108.105.59
RewriteRule ^.*$  http://site.dev [L]
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou tentar!